# Alternative for (adjusted-) $R^2$ with different (non-nested I believe) linear regression models

Tags: regression, linear

I've ran into a problem which I could use some guidance on, since my academical background so far couldn't provide me with the answer. I am also reading some papers hoping to give me some valuable insights but I am having trouble reading and understanding them, so I decided to ask this question here as well.

For my master's thesis I plan to distribute 3 different questionnaires. One with an open question, one with a closed question and one mixed design. They are questions meant to explain the respondents prior given rating of some service.

Every respondent will receive only one format, and the sample is not random. I was planning on simply comparing the adjusted $R^2$ of the three models but I don't think that is the correct way to do things, since differences in $R^2$ could be caused by differences in the population rather than the format. The goal of the research is to make some preliminary conclusions about which format (open, closed or mixed) explains most variance in the dependent variable. Of course not generalizable because of the non-random sample.

Is there a good way to cope with this? Am I right when I say I'm trying to compare different non-nested linear models?

Comment: What do you mean with "not random"? Does this means that the three questionnaires are distributed to different groups of people in an exclusive fashion, e.g. questionnaire 1 goes to students from Dorm A, questionnaire 2 goes to students from Dorm B, etc. If so, there is no way to differentiate effects of questionnaire from effects of group (flawed design). If "not random" just means that all questionnaires were answered by one group not representative of the general population, then this is not an issue. Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I meant the latter! I'd like to (and I hope this is possible) distribute 1 link of the questionnaire and have people get assigned one version of the questionnaire only. Will dive into that later :) I believe this is possible in Qualtrics, however.

Comment: Do the questionnaires yield one dependent variable (e.g. summary score) or multiple varibles (e.g. several item scores)? What analysis software are you using?

Comment: They all yield one dependent variable. The independent variables will be dummies of things mentioned/not mentioned. I'll most likely be using SPSS :)

Comment: Have you considered using a one-way  ANOVA testing  mean differences in outcome between the three groups?

Comment: Uuhm I haven't actually, since the goal of the study is to draw preliminary conclusions about which format gives more insights in the given score (Y). Tbf, it's been a while since I've last done an ANOVA test, Ill give it some thought tonight!